# Can you retrieve a property using document.getElementById?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a button with `background-color:#FF0000`, and I want to store that property (color) into a variable. I have tried this:

```
var x=document.getElementById("button1").style.background;
```

but it does not work.

Here is the snippet of the full code:-

```
<html>
<body>

<button id="button1" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:#00FF00;font-color:white" type="button" onclick="colorchange()">this is green</button>

<button id="button2" style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color:#FF0000;font-color:white" type="button" onclick="colorchange()">this is red</button>

<script>
function colorchange()
{
var color1;
var color2;
var color3;

color1=document.getElementById("button1").style.background
color2=document.getElementById("button2").style.background

color3=color1;
color1=color2;
color2=color3;

document.getElementById("button1").style.background=color1
document.getElementById("button2").style.background=color2
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that I can't seem to store the background-color into the variables.

Comment: Is this a `style` attribute on the button, or a style applied by a stylesheet?

Comment: `var x=document.getElementById("button1").style.background;` You missed a '.'

Comment: I edited my answer to fit your edit. Please see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

### After your last edit

You have to declare your JavaScript function before you can reference it in your HTML!
So move your `<script>` block above the buttons.

See the differences here:

- [Original code](http://jsfiddle.net/ska2L/2/): yields errors in the console
- [JS code in `<head>` tag](http://jsfiddle.net/ska2L/3/): functions correctly!

Nevertheless, I would advise you to create the event listener bindings in your JS:

```
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", colorchange);
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", colorchange);
```

Caching the button references for further reuse should also be considered:

```
var btn1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("button1");
```

---

### Original answer

a) You're missing a period.

b) I would advise you to use `backgroundColor` since you're using it in CSS either.

```
alert( document.getElementById("button1").style.backgroundColor );
                                         ^----- period here
```

If you supplied your CSS property via a style sheet (instead of the `style` HTML attribute), this value won't be accessible through the `style` attribute either.
You have to use [window.getComputedStyle(elem)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle):

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("button1")).backgroundColor
```

Comment: a semicolon? are you sure you don't mean a period?

Comment: @Eonasdan Thanks, you're right, of course! I've corrected it and inserted a hint.